# Monolog doesn't log the entries in Symfony API Platform

Tags: php, symfony4, api-platform.com

Following is my handler.

```
    use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
    use Entity\Import as ImportEntity;
    
    class ImportHandler {
         public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger) {
                $this->logger = $logger;
         }
         public function handle(ImportEntity $data): array {
            $this->logger->error("hi");
         }
    }
```

But \var\log\dev.log doesn't have this entry "hi".

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
            channels: ["!event"]
        # uncomment to get logging in your browser
        # you may have to allow bigger header sizes in your Web server configuration
        #firephp:
        #    type: firephp
        #    level: info
        #chromephp:
        #    type: chromephp
        #    level: info
        console:
            type: console
            process_psr_3_messages: false
            channels: ["!event", "!doctrine", "!console"]
```

This is my monolog configuration.

Comment: make sure you have `composer require symfony/monolog-bundle` installed and that you `chmod -R 777 var/log` in your app directory

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is the handler called in any way? This could help to search for the bug: distinguish whether this is a problem of API Platform, or of Monolog